# Doing a backup of a file on hourly basis in Luigi

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, luigi

I'm trying to backup a in Memory file on disk every hour using Luigi i.e. to say, Every hour I want to runrun_backup Task and check if function func_backup() return True or not, if yes Then I save the file on disk. (below is the Code that I have tried):

```
df_dumm = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[1,2,3]})
def func_backup():
   df_dumm.to_csv('test.csv')

class run_backup(luigi.Task):
   status = False
   def run(self):
      self.status = True if func_backup() else False
   def complete(self):
      return  True #hard Code to test Overall Task

class BackupScheduler(luigi.Task):
   def run(self):
      RangeHourlyBase(of=run_backup,start=datetime.date.today(),param_name='test')
   def output(self):
      return luigi.LocalTarget(r'Backup_{}'.format(2) )

if __name__ =='main':
  luigi.build([ChainedTasks(ids)], workers=1,local_scheduler=False,no_lock=True,detailed_summary=True)
```

However I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "\lib\site-packages\luigi\worker.py", line 184, in run
raise RuntimeError('Unfulfilled %s at run time: %s' % (deps, ', '.join(missing)))
RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: BackupScheduler__99914b932b
```

How can I run RangeHourlyBase() inside Python rather than command line?

Comment: 1. I hope that isn't your actual formatting, otherwise the classes aren't being created correctly. 2. By definition, a `luigi.ExternalTask` does not have a run, so you may be using it improperly. 3. Can you provide a minimal code example? We don't know what `RangeHourlyBase` is supposed to do.

Comment: 1. Here in text Editor it doesnt allow tab, but I have edited the formatting. 2. Changed ExternalTask to Task. 3. Provided an minimal example, where RangeHourlyBase should save the csv file every hour.

Comment: Have you tried running `BackupScheduler` on its own? Still don't see how `RangeHourlyBase` interacts with the output of the task, which is probably your issue. Would be great if you could show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add more Details for what I want to achieve

Comment: BackupScheduler works if I run like  :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     luigi.run([RangeHourlyBase, '--of', BackupScheduler , '--start', '2020-03-03T1020', '--stop','2020-03-04T1550''--workers', '1'])

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, because I don't know what RangeHourlyBase does. Please show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: RangeHourlyBase is a Luigi function from the range module. https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.tools.range.html#luigi.tools.range.RangeHourlyBase